# PowerBuilder App - Database transaction information not available

Tags: powerbuilder, windows-10-universal

We have an older PowerBuilder application which is getting moved from Windows 7 to WIndows 10.  When launched on Windows 10 it only gives the following error:

**Database transaction information not available**

**Call SetTrans or SetTransObject function.**

[Error prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucCm3.png)

Windows 10 does not have the following drivers that Windows 7 has, and I'm listing them below.  Could that be one of the reasons?  I don't want to sway anyone thinking about drivers though.

- ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server, Version: 2014.120.2000.08, Microsoft
  Corporation, File: MSODBCSQL11, Date: 2/21/2014
- SQL Native Client, Version: 2005.90.5000.00, Microsoft Corporation,
  SQLNCLI.DLL, Date: 12/10/2010
- SQL Server, Version 6.01.7601.17514, Microsoft Corporation,
  SQLSRV32.DLL, Date: 11/20/2010
- SQL Server Native Client 10.0, Version 2009.100.1600.01, Microsoft
  Corporation, SQLNCLI10.DLL, Date 4/3/2010
- SQL Server Native Client 11.0, Version 2011.110.2100.60, Microsoft
  Corporation, SQLNCLI11.DLL, 2/11/2012

The database is SQL Server 2008 R2, and we know it isn't supported from Windows 10, but other PowerBuilder applications on Windows 10 work with that SQL Server version.  That's one of the reasons we're confused.

Answer (score 0):

IF there are no SQL drivers you won't be connecting to the database.  You need to install the drivers.  Exactly which one I can't say since you provided no information on which connection parameters the application uses.

Answer (score 0):

Doublecheck that you've installed the 32-bit driver for SQLServer 2008 R2.  Installing the SQLServer client on Windows10 will install the 64-bit driver by default...

-Paul-